# Format rest response in angular js without ng bind html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So basically the issue I am facing is that I have a database with a lot of data in it. So when i query using $http, i get a response. The response is a large amount of data and when I bind it to the model it's very difficult to read the data.

So currently I post data into the database from an android app with html tags and then use ng-bind html to render it as html. This is causing trouble analyzing the data. What can be done to avoid HTML tags and still render the data so it is readable. The attached images will further help you understand.

This is how it looks with html tags and ng bind

[image]

This is how it looks without html tags, not very pretty and readabale.

[image]

[The highlighted portion is how the data arrives. I need to get rid of those tags which are messing up the database. However the entire complaint portion value is associated with one key.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dZSV.png)

Comment: How is it difficult to read the data? Judging from your screenshot, this does not look like a lot of data. I don't think you should post data with HTML tags into a database. At least use JSON (if you are already abusing a database) and then properly build a layout with HTML.

Comment: @Veluria It's something that Doctors will read and in this particular case the data is not that much. Otherwise it's like 3-4 times of this data.

Comment: @HardikNagda can you show how the data looks like when it arrives? It would be nice if it was JSON

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Yes it is Json, have attached an image!

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem while working on my project. And the easiest solution I get is to use the markdown language.In this, you can store your data in the form of markdowns and when you retrieve them by using markdown parser you will get a better data. there are a lot of markdown parser available. I recommend using "marked.js".